# RxJS v6.3 pipe - How to use it?

Tags: rxjs

I just created a new Angular app that installed the new RxJS v6.3 (released 6 days ago), which "fixed" a problem with pipe and strong typing.

With v6.2 I could specify only the final returning value of the pipe (in this case, `.pipe<User>`, like this:

```js
getStatus(): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.get('/user/status')
    .pipe<User>(
      tap(foo, bar),
      finalize(() => this.requestEnded()),
      map((resp) => new User(resp.user)));
}
```

But in the new version they removed that possibility in the Observable class (they fixed this line from [v6.2.2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.2/src/internal/Observable.ts#L299), to this in [v6.3](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.0/src/internal/Observable.ts#L299)). The IDE complains with this message:

> Expected at least 0 arguments, but got 1 or more.

Now I am forced to specify types for every function in the pipe, something like this:

```js
getStatus(): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.get('/user/status')
    // If I have 3 piped functions I have to specify all 3 types
    .pipe<{}, {}, User>(
      tap(foo, bar),
      finalize(() => this.requestEnded()),
      // I even have to specify type for this parameter (resp)
      map((resp: {user}) => new User(resp.user))); 
}
```

Was this really intended? Note that this is a "fix" to pipe, which means to me that pipe was always supposed to work like that. Or am I using it the wrong way?

I even had this function that worked nicely, I just passed in some "common pipes" that I wanted to execute for every request:

```js
logIn(username: string, password: string, remember: boolean) {
  return this.http.post('/user/login', { username, password, remember })
    .pipe<User>(
      ...this.commonPipes(),
      map(resp => new User(resp.user)));
}
```

But now, how am I supposed to specify types for that?

This change was [introduced in v6.3](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#630-2018-08-30) which says it "fixes" some error with pipe (it references [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3945)). I write "fixes" because for me it broke things, it's not backwards compatible, and I haven't found a "how to upgrade" guide that explains how to use the new, fixed `pipe()`.

Comment: Just take a look PR diff and other tests inside the repo - https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/commit/872b0ec

Comment: Wow, I just noticed the problem only occurs when I do that weird thing of `.pipe(...this.commonPipes())`. This question is too big and silly for this silly error of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the spread syntax could only be used in a couple of versions in which the signatures for `pipe` were 'fixed'. However, those 'fixes' essentially broke all type checking for `pipe` - which was far worse, so they were reverted and changed again.

As noted in [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3989), using the spread syntax with `pipe` requires TypeScript 3.0 - as it supports tuple parameter extraction and spreading.

As an alternative to having `commonPipes` return an array of operators, you could look at using the static `pipe` function to compose the operators into a single operator that can then be passed to an observable's `pipe` method.

Have a look at my [Combining Operators](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-combining-operators-397bad0628d0) article.

Comment: This was the answer I was expecting. Thank you.